# Amazon GameCircle on First Generation (1st) Kindle Fire Initializes as Guest

Tags: android, profile, kindle-fire

I am trying to use the Whispersync feature of Amazon GameCircle.

When my app's first Activity is created, I check to see whether the AmazonGamesClient is initialized; if not, I call the `Initialize(...)` function. I have followed the directions pretty closely given on Amazon's developer portal:

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/gamecircle/documentation/gamecircle-config.html
https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/gamecircle/documentation/gamecircle-init.html
https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/gamecircle/documentation/whispersync.html

The issue that I'm seeing is this: when my app starts up and it initializes, everything works great on all modern Kindle Fires, with a little GameCircle pop-up that says "Welcome [whatever your username is]".  However, on the 1st Generation Kindle Fire, the pop-up says "Welcome Guest. This game supports Amazon GameCircle".  It never seems to be able to connect correctly to my Amazon account.

I have noted that on the 1st Generation Kindle, I get the following lines in Log Cat:

```
11-29 18:46:00.319: D/GC_Whispersync(2906): Checking whether Whispersync is enabled
11-29 18:46:00.499: D/GC_NativeKindleFireStateCallHandler(2906): Processing request [backgroundwebview-23] for call type [isWhispersyncEnabled]
11-29 18:46:00.499: D/KindleFireIPCProxy(2906): Checking isWhispersyncEnabled: false
11-29 18:46:00.530: D/GC_Whispersync(2906): Whispersync is DISABLED
11-29 18:46:00.530: D/GC_Whispersync(2906): Cannot call the service because whispersync is disabled
```

However, the little GameCircle pop-up has a "connect" button that I have tried to use numerous times to connect to my Amazon account - it just doesn't seem to be working correctly.

I have downloaded quite a few apps that use GameCircle, and I am seeing similar behavior in MOST of them.  However, a few of them successfully connect.  I noticed that a game called Mega Jump connects correctly, and two called Super Hero Birds and Witz Free connect on their second attempt.

Once one of those games connects, my app connects correctly every time thereafter!

Any thoughts on how those games are able to connect to the Amazon profile?  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Thank you!

Comment: Same issue here, would love to hear from anyone on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try publishing one of your leaderboards.

I had this problem for a while before I set one of my leaderboards to Published. On my Android device, the app would take me to a browser to log in  and then when I came back to the app, it would still show as a guest. Since I published one of my leaderboards, though, I have been able to log in on the first or second attempt on each of my test devices.